# How to authenticate via session in the Spring Security from Angular?

Tags: java, angular, security, spring-security, session-cookies

So I have an Angular frontend application, and a Spring backend. Currently, it seems that I have a cookie of JSessionId on my application (which I receive only on login, and not on register, for whatever reason)
[(cookies)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVeKm.png)

I assume it sends those cookies back to the server. (though that's only an assumption)

Now, when I am making a request to the protected server, the only thing I get is this "Please login" popup.
[Login popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEH5z.png)

When I log in, my [UserService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvt38.png) logs a user with such details:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User(userId=1, name=Maksym Riabov, username=MRiabov, password={bcrypt}$2a$10$W0XJRQdfxV5XXORkr2bTluIHvFetIVBzmVp51l39T5zLCQk12RV1i, company=null, enabled=true), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]
```

And what I've noticed is that the sessionId is null there. Why could that be?

To answer some of the questions forward:

- Yes, I've pasted {withCredentials: true} to every request. (specific to Angular)
- Yes, I've read documentation - I've even tried pasting all the code from it and it seems that it didn't work.

My login controller:

```
@GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return ResponseEntity.ok("123123");
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> register(@RequestBody UserRegisterDto userDto) {
        //todo check if name taken
        User user = userMapper.toEntity2(userDto);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setEnabled(true);
        //todo remove
        Authority authority = authorityRepository.save(new Authority("ADMIN"));
        user.setAuthorities(Set.of(authority));
        //todo REMOVE!!!!

        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
        System.out.println("registration works!");

        return ResponseEntity.ok(Map.of("result",authority.getAuthority().getAuthority()));
    }
```

Now, I am sending a request to the backend (which puts the popup above) like this one:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<OnboardingPathDto> createOnboardingPath() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        // erased a bit of code here
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
```

And as you see I have a method security, which throws the request for auth.

And, the cherry at the top:

```
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests() 
                .anyRequest().permitAll() //todo this is unsafe
                .and().sessionManagement(session -> session.
                        sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                        .maximumSessions(1))//to force only one session per user
     //here I tried sessionManagement to do something, but did it do something?
                .rememberMe((rememberMe) -> rememberMe.userDetailsService(userDetailsService))
                .httpBasic(); 
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider) throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(daoAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider prov(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserDetailsService userDetailService) throws Exception {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {//to force only one session per user
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
```

I've read through the Spring Security documentation far and wide, and even have taken a course in it, but I still couldn't manage to get it working.

So, what I'm struggling with:

- ### Why can't Spring authenticate through the session even though it is configured to do so? Where is my error?

Edit: I assume that sending the session directly into Angular (in REST, not in cookie) is really unsafe, right? I currently rely on cookies.

Edit 2: ffs, I'm sick of it, I'm just going to do oauth2 authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Edit: I assume that sending the session directly into Angular (in REST, not in cookie) is really unsafe, right? I currently rely on cookies.

You are right, this is a bad idea. For sessions in an application running in a browser, only use cookies with those two flag raised (value=`true`):

- `secure` (exchanged only over https)
- `http-only` (hidden from Javascript).

This means that cookies should not be accessible to the Angular code but automatically set by the browser before sending requests to the backend.

You should also implement CSRF protection (which is the default in spring-security).

> Edit 2: ffs, I'm sick of it, I'm just going to do oauth2 authentication.

Good idea. This is much better for security, user experience (SSO), and developper experience: most OIDC providers, either on premise (like Keycloak), or in the cloud (like Auth0, Cognito, and many others), already provide with login forms (including **M**ulti **F**actor **A**uthentication), user registration, profile edition, administration screens (like clients declaration, user roles assignement, etc.). For that:

- configure your Spring REST API as a resource-server. I have written tutorials for this [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials)
- configure your Angular app either as:

  - an OAuth2 client. My favorite certified lib for Angular is [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client)
  - a BFF client. **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend is a pattern where a server-side middleware serves as the only OAuth2 client to hide tokens from the browser. Angular app won't be OAuth2: it will be secured with sessions (haha! your devil is back ;-), the middleware (something like spring-cloud-gateway with `tokenRelay` filter) will keep this session, associate tokens to it and replace sessions with tokens before forwarding requests to resource-server. [Tutorial there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).

Comment: I just created a tutorial for implementing the BFF pattern with spring-cloud-gateway: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff

Comment: my man, you really are a ch4mp... – 
Edit: Quite frankly, that doesn't even compile...

Comment: What doesn't compile? Because there is a CI configured (Github action). Every thing compiles and tests pass...